# Printing the actual negative number stored inside unsigned int

Tags: c

I have a strange problem. I have a variable whose actual value is only negative(only negative integers are generated for this variable). But in the legacy code, an old colleague of mine used uint16 instead of signed int to store the values of that variable. Now if i wanted to print the actual negative value of that variable, how can i do that(what format specifier to us)? For example if actual value is -75, when i print using %d its giving me 5 digit positive value(I think its because of two's complement). I want to print it as 75 or -75.

Comment: Cast the variable in the print call.  `printf("value = %d\n", (int)value);`

Comment: What is with all the answers attempting to use fancy features with unions or specifier abuse? Just subtract 65536. Done. Standard, defined, simple.

Comment: It'd help a lot if we knew details, in particular what is sizeof(int).  Whether it's 2 or 4 makes quite a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a 16-bit negative integer was stored in a `uint16_t` called `x`, then the original value may be calculated as `x-65536`.

This can be printed with any of<sup>1</sup>:

```
printf("%ld", x-65536L);

printf("%d", (int) (x-65536));

int y = x-65536;
printf("%d", y);
```

Subtracting 65536 works because:

- Per C 2018 6.5.16.1 2, the value of the right operand (a negative 16-bit integer is converted to the type of the assignment expression (which is essentially the type of the left operand).
- Per 6.3.1.3 2, the conversion to an unsigned integer operates by adding or subtracting “one more than the maximum value that can be represented in the new type”. For `uint16_t`, one more than its maximum is 65536.
- With a 16-bit negative integer, adding 65536 once brings it into the range of a `uint16_t`.
- Therefore, subtracting 65536 restores the original value.

### Footnote

<sup>1</sup> `65536` will be `long` or `int` according to whether `int` is 16 bits or more, so these statements are careful to handle the type correctly. The first uses `65536L` to ensure the type is `long`. The rest convert the value to `int`. This is safe because, although the type of `x-65536` could be `long`, its value fits in an `int`—unless you are executing in a C implementation that limits `int` to −32767 to +32767, and the original value may be −32768, in which case you should stick to the first option.

Comment: You might want to add the note that this will only work if `sizeof(int) > 2`.  There are still compilers out there using 16 bit ints.  Mostly in the embedded space, e.g. the Arduino: https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/data-types/int/

Comment: @dgnuff: If `int` is 16 bits, then `65536` is a long, and, in `x-65536`, `x` is converted to a long, and then the resulting value is correct.

Answer (score 1):

If an `int` is 32 bits on your system, then the correct format for printing a 16-bit int is `%hu` for unsigned and `%hd` for signed.

Examine the output of:

```
uint16_t n = (uint16_t)-75;

printf("%d\n", (int)n); // Output: 65461
printf("%hu\n", n); // Output: 65461
printf("%hd\n", n); // Output: -75
```

Comment: The C standard does not guarantee this will work. The behavior is implementation defined. Per C 2018 7.21.6.1 7, the value of the argument for `%hd` is converted to a `short int`. Per 6.3.1.3 3, the behavior of this conversion is implementation-defined.

Comment: Correct specifiers for `(u)int16_t` are `"%" PRIu16` and `"%" PRId16` from `<inttypes.h>`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: The Standard makes no attempt to forbid implementations from behaving in obtuse fashion.  Unless one is using an unusual platform, an obtuse compiler, or a compiler that's configured to squawk at actions which are defined but unusual, `(int16_t)65461` is going to equal -75.  A bigger issue from a practical perspective would be that not all printf libraries implement everything included in the spec.

Comment: @supercat: Writing code based on personal opinions about what compilers ought to do is not engineering. It is okay to deviate from the C standard when circumstances warrant **and it is documented**, and, to the extent feasible, undesired behaviors are guarded against with tests. However, in this case, there is no warrant: It is entirely feasible to write uncomplicated strictly conforming code that solves the problem. Relying on non-conforming behaviors is a shortcoming of the code in this answer. (Incidentally, there is no conversion to `(int16_t)` involved.)

Comment: @EricPostpischil: The Standard has never attempted to specify everything necessary to make an implementation suitable for any particular purpose.  Indeed, the authors explicitly note in the Rationale that an implementation could be "conforming" without being suitable for any particular purpose.  When the authors of the C Standard described in the Rationale how "the majority of current implementations" would process `unsigned short a=60000,b=62500; unsigned c=a*b;`, did they mean that the majority of implementations explicitly documented such behavior, or that...

Comment: ...they thought that the tradition of how such actions should be handled on commonplace platforms was sufficiently strong and unambiguous that there was no reason to contemplate the notion of compilers doing anything else except when targeting unusual platforms where other behaviors might make more sense?

Comment: @EricPostpischil: PS--while it's possible that an implementation might define `uint16_t` and yet define the `short int` as a different type from  `int16_t`, such behavior would be sufficiently unusual that I'd be surprised if *any* non-contrived implementations of C99 or later have ever done so.

Comment: @supercat: Your comments are a non sequitur. My previous comment did not argue in any way about what the standard said, so responding with some argument about what the standard says or does not say or what its purpose is has no bearing. Even if you were completely write about the standard and its purposes, the fact remains that writing code based on personal opinions about what compilers ought to do is not engineering, and it is clearly inferior to using a solution that is simply and clearly conforming.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: My "personal opinions about what compilers ought to do" are, in this case, backed up by decades observations of what general-purpose compilers for commonplace platforms have historically, *unanimously*, done.  While there are a number of ways of interpreting an attempt to convert an out-of-range value to a small signed integer type, and they would yield different results when using ones'-complement or sign-magnitude representations, they all yield the same value when using two's-complement representation.

Comment: @supercat: You have missed the point completely. I did not comment at all on whether your personal opinions were correct or not. The point is simply that writing code based on opinion is not engineering. If you write code whose behavior is defined by one or more specifications, that is engineering. If you wrote code is behavior predicted from personal opinions, that is not engineering.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: Many specifications are incomplete.  In many fields, the only way to design anything would be to use judgment to fill in the gaps of incomplete specs.  For example, a typical microcontroller may specify that it is suitable for use at voltages between 2.5 and 5.5 volts, and specify that it runs at 3.9+/0.3MHz at 3.0 volts and 4.1+/-0.3MHz at 5.0 volts.  If I need a part that runs somewhere between 3 and 5 MHz for any voltage between 4.9 and 5.1, should this part be suitable?  I'd say that it should be, even though nothing in the data sheet actually says....

Comment: ...that the part won't speed up to 8Mhz when fed exactly 4.93 volts.  As a matter of judgment, I'd allow for the possibility that the part might run slightly faster at e.g. 3.5 volts than at anything higher or lower, but probably not by more than the amount of uncertainty given in the 3.0 and 5.0 volt specs.

Comment: @supercat: You can have all the judgment, opinions, and unfilled needs you want. It still is not engineering. Needing a dog does not make a cat into a dog. Engineering is writing code based based on specifications. If it is based on opinion or judgment, it might serve your purposes, it might fill a need you have, but it is not engineering.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: Is there any *documented* basis for expecting that typical C implementations won't overflow the stack when nesting function calls three deep, or when creating a VLA with two elements?  Or is the fact that most programs don't bomb the stack merely a matter of happenstance?  It would be great if C were sufficiently well specified that most tasks could be accomplished without reliance upon anything that wasn't guaranteed by spec, but since it isn't, I guess engineering is essentially impossible in C.

Comment: @supercat: For current macOS, the default stack size is 8 MiB for the main thread and 2 MiB for others (and you can request more), and you can use `-Wframe-larger-than=<n>` to advise if a fixed-size (no VLA) stack frame exceeds a requested amount. So, yes, you can determine if a program will fit and can design one to do so. I am sure Unix generally and Windows also publish default stack sizes and let you request non-default stack sizes. I do not know that they have an analog of `-Wframe-larger-than`, but I do not claim that one is engineering properly without it.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: I haven't noticed `-Wframe-larger-than`; I've certainly seldom seen it used.  Does gcc offer any guarantee how much the stack usage of a function might exceed the specified value without issuing a diagnostic, since frame size doesn't include everything that goes on the stack?

Comment: @supercat: In a routine with VLAs, what do you anticipate going on the stack that is not included in frame size? In a routine without VLAs, I would expect the compiler to compute the frame size as the largest amount it puts on the stack in any path through the routine.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: Even in a routine without VLAs, there will often be miscellaneous register pushes that don't get counted in the total, along with the space used by the processor to store the return address.  If such things were guaranteed as never exceeding a total of e.g. 128 bytes, one could simply subtract 128 from the warning threshold, but I don't know if there's a documented limit as to how much stack a function might use beyond the reported frame size.

Comment: @supercat: I expect the compiler counts all of its pushes in the stack frame. I somewhat recall that either Clang or GCC uses a fixed size (at least in the Apple version, and again in the absence of VLAs), meaning that, at the beginning of the routine, it decrements a constant from the stack pointer (possibly modulo some alignment fiddling) and keeps all its data above that, not doing pushes or pops within the routine. I am not privy to the decisions behind that, as I would think allowing for small frames when a function goes through one path and large in another would have some benefit.

Comment: @supercat: In any case, the compiler can certainly evaluate all paths it generates and count the size as the largest amount it puts on the stack including any miscellaneous pushes. If `-Wframe-larger-than` is not doing that, it is broken. As I recall, it was added at my request—I filed a feature request in Apple for it, so we could ensure routines inside the kernel, with its limited stack, were not using too much stack space, and, sometime later, the feature was added. (There could have been other people asking for it too.) So, if it does not include everything, it is not serving its purpose.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: In that case, you should file a defect report, since I doubt the threshold at which it issues the warnings is ever correct.  Further, if the feature was  only added at your request, I'm curious if and how you think anyone would have done any proper engineering with gcc before that.

Comment: As a simple example of where the threshold is obviously wrong, `void someFunc(void); int foo(int index) { char space[1024] = {1,2,3}; dummyFunc(); return space[index]; }`.  Squawks if threshold is set to 1023; doesn't squawk if set to 1024.  Actual stack usage, however, is 1040 bytes.

Comment: @supercat: [GCC 8.2 warns for `-Wframe-larger-than=1024`.](https://godbolt.org/z/Jmjgj8) If `-O3` is added, it changes the code so that only 1024 is subtracted from the stack pointer, instead of 1040, and does not warn. (I had to change your `dummyFunc` to `someFunc`.)

Comment: @EricPostpischil: I was using -O3, and it subtracted 1024 from SP, but the actual stack usage in that case is 8 for the return address, 8 for the push RBX, and 1024 for the SUB SP, for a total of 1040.

Comment: As another example: `#define z7 ,e,e,e,e,e,e,e, e,e,e,e,e,e,e

long qfunc(long e, ...)
{
    long q[32]={1,2,3,4,5};
    if (e <= 0) return q[-e];
    else return qfunc(
        (e-1) z7 z7 z7  z7 z7 z7  z7 z7 z7
    );
}`, tested with -Wframe-larger-than=256.  Changing the size of the array to 33 yields a warning, but stack usage per recursive call is well over five times the requested 256-byte limit.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: Incidentally, it's possible to write a recursive function that abides the C11 "Translation limits" specs and compiles cleanly with -Wframe-larger-than=16--but uses more than 8,000,000 bytes per recursive call--a factor-of-500,000 difference between the warning threshold and actual stack usage.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your friend has somehow correctly put the bit representation for the signed integer into the unsigned integer, the only standard compliant way to extract it back would be to use a union as-

```
typedef union {
    uint16_t input;
    int16_t output;
} aliaser;
```

Now, in your code you can do -

```
aliaser x;
x.input = foo;
printf("%d", x.output);
```

Comment: `Assuming your friend has somehow correctly put the bit representation for the signed integer into the unsigned integer` <- this is as simple as `T foo = (T)-42;`

Comment: This is not the only standard compliant way. Simply subtracting 65536 restores the original value.

Comment: @chux yes, I agree. Default arguments promotion takes place. Will remove it

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <inttypes.h>

uint16_t foo = -75;
printf("==> %" PRId16 " <==\n", foo); // type mismatch, undefined behavior
```

Comment: `PRI16D` is defined for formatting an `int16_t`, not for reinterpreting the value of a `uint16_t`. The C standard does not define the behavior when used in this way.

Answer (score 0):

Go ahead with the union, as explained by another answer. Just wanted to say that if you are using GCC, there's a very cool feature that allows you to do that sort of "bitwise" casting without writing much code:

```
printf("%d", ((union {uint16_t in; int16_t out}) foo).out);
```

See https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.4.1/gcc/Cast-to-Union.html.

Comment: This can be done without GCC extensions by using the C standard compound literals.

Comment: I get "warning: ISO C forbids casts to union type [-Wpedantic]".  Suggest `printf("%d\n", (union x {uint16_t in; int16_t out;}) {foo}.out);`

Answer (score 0):

If `u` is an object of unsigned integer type and a negative number whose magnitude is within range of `u`'s type is stored into it, storing `-u` to an object of `u`'s type will leave it holding the magnitude of that negative number.  This behavior does not depend upon how `u` is represented.  For example, if `u` and `v` are 16-bit `unsigned short`, but `int` is 32 bits, then storing -60000 into `u` will leave it holding `5536` [the implementation will behave as though it adds 65536 to the value stored until it's within range of `unsigned short`].  Evaluating `-u` will yield -5536, and storing -5536 into `v` will leave it holding 60000.